# How to combine jq array value into same key in json file in shell script?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with this content:

```
[
  {
    "id": "one",
    "msg": [
      "test"
    ],
    "FilePath": [
      "JsonSerializer.cs",
      "ChatClient.cs",
      "MiniJSON.cs"
    ],
    "line": [
      358,
      1241,
      382
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "two",
    "msg": [
      "secondtest"
    ],
    "FilePath": [
      "Utilities.cs",
      "PhotonPing.cs"
    ],
    "line": [
      88,
      36
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the output where as you can see the value combine into one :

```
one
[
  "test"
]
[
  "JsonSerializer.cs",358
  "ChatClient.cs",1241
  "MiniJSON.cs",382
]

two
[
  "secondtest"
]
[
  "Utilities.cs",88
  "PhotonPing.cs",36
]
```

I have tried this `cat stack.json |jq -r '.[]|.id,.msg,.FilePath,.line'`
which gave output as

```
  one
    [
      "test"
    ]
    [
      "JsonSerializer.cs",
      "ChatClient.cs",
      "MiniJSON.cs"
    ]
    [
      358,
      1241,
      382
    ]
    two
    [
      "secondtest"
    ]
    [
      "Utilities.cs",
      "PhotonPing.cs"
    ]
    [
      88,
      36
    ]
```

Kindly help me resolve this, I have tried a lot to debug this but unable to get through. Also, the Filepath and line would always be similar for each . For example if FilePath has 3, line would also have 3 values.

Comment: The expected output as shown is neither valid JSON nor an interleaved stream of valid JSON texts and raw strings. Please clarify what output would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`transpose`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#transpose).

```
.[] | .id, .msg, ([.FilePath, .line] | transpose | add), ""
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/udgsUPSndlx)</sup>

Comment: The transpose|add pipeline is so elegant. I came up with the clunky `(. as $o | reduce range(.FilePath | length) as $i ([]; . + [$o.FilePath[$i], $o.line[$i]]))`

Comment: @glennjackman Cool. I saw your exercism profile, have you tried solving the satellite challenge using JQ? That's way cooler

Comment: heh. not yet...

Comment: https://github.com/exercism/jq/blob/main/exercises/practice/satellite/.meta/example.jq

Comment: @glennjackman At first glance, `is_unique` could've simply been defined as `length == (unique | length)` , is there a particular reason why you used `reduce`? ..Aand `(.inorder | sort) == (.preorder | sort)` for `validate_elements`. I like `build_tree` though, far more cleaner than [mine](https://gist.github.com/oguz-ismail/5f4e18f229f7a56691a17f7d91af7637) :D

Comment: `unique`! D'oh, I knew there had to be a better way.

Comment: there, it's much better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<stack.json jq -r '.[] | .id, .msg, ([.FilePath, .line]|transpose|add)'
```

gives the output as required by you.

`transpose` turns `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` into `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]` and `add` collects all array elements into a single array.

If you are looking to have file path and line number in a single line, I suggest formatting them as string, separated by colon:

```
.[] | .id, .msg, ([.FilePath, .line]|transpose|map(join(":")))
```

Comment: Your program produces output that includes commas that the "expected output" does not have.

Comment: @peak thanks, a valid point. Let's wait for the author to clarify if a typo in the requirements or if an invalid JSON output is indeed expected.

Comment: @knittl Many thanks for your ans. That file was originally a json one which after some data manipulation resulted into the one i posted (which now becomes a non-json format) . As suggested , transpose works for my problem.